# How do integers value pass into the pointer using scanf()?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

How does this line work `scanf("%d",ptr++);` in the code below? The value scan by pointer store as an address or store in the place where the pointer pointed to? When I `printf("%d", *ptr);`, only garbage was appeared. I would really like to know where the input data are stored.Thank you in advance.

```
int main()
{
    int index, max, numArray[10];
    int *ptr=0;
    ptr = numArray;

    printf("Enter 10 numbers: \n");
    for(index=0;index<10;index++)
    {
        scanf("%d",ptr++);
    }

    ptr=numArray;
    max=*ptr;
    for(index=0;index<10;index++)
    {
        if(*ptr>max)
            max=*ptr;
        ptr++;
    }

    printf("max is %d.\n", max);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a good place to start: https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf

Comment: Also have a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: The `printf("%d", *ptr);` you mention in your question is not in your code, so it's somewhat hard to answer that part of the question.

Answer (score 4):

> The value scan by pointer store as an address or store in the place where the pointer pointed to?

The latter. You give `scanf()` the **location** of (aka, a pointer to) a variable where it should store its result.

> When I `printf("%d", *ptr);`, only garbage was appeared

In your program, `ptr` is constantly modified, to make it point to the individual elements of your `numArray`. The `ptr++` advances the pointer by one, but evaluates to the original value. So if you put this `printf` directly after your `scanf`, `scanf()` would have written e.g. to index 4, but because of the `++`, `printf` will print index 5. This isn't initialized yet, so probably contains some *random* data. In terms of C, it's just **undefined behavior** to use an uninitialized value.

What should work in this place is something like `printf("%d", *(ptr-1));`, but this would be a very strange way to write the whole thing. Maybe rewrite the first loop to something like

```
for(index=0;index<10;index++)
{
    scanf("%d", ptr);
    printf("%d", *ptr);
    ++ptr;
}
```

so incrementing the pointer only happens **after** you used it in your `printf`.

Comment: Ahh, sorry. I almost skipped it. Deleting the comment!